# Shapefile CRS damaged. How to bring it back?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have two shapefiles with same location and extends (EPSG 4326). But one of the shapefiles CRS seems to be damaged after doing a lot wrong with reprojection... its not shown on the same position as the first, not damaged one.

Both have just to be on the same "place". How can I do that?

Damaged:
[image: damaged]

Good:
[image: good]

Comment: Neither of the layers seems to be correct. Both layer's extents are impossible for EPSG:4326 which is limited to -180<x<180 and -90<y<90.

Comment: Do you have the original, before messing with the CRS? If the original was in some other CRS, and you don't know what it was, there's probably not much to be done. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extent of both files looks like you have reprojected the data to a projected CRS, but then assigned a longlat CRS in the end. In this way, units are metres, not degrees as it should be with longlat.

If you know which CRS you have reprojected to, you can assign that to the shapefile with `Vector -> Data Management Tools -> Define current projection`, and then reproject the data to WGS84 with Rightclick `-> Save As...` and choosing the CRS.

If you don't know, but can give the extent of the original shapefile in degrees, we could try to find out the projected CRS.

---

**EDIT**

UTM 39N (EPSG:32639) applied to the first extent looks rather good:

[image]

red stars are "bad" UTM39N coordinates, green ones "good" UTM 36N coordinates.

Comment: I dont know. I guess I typed in a wrong EPSG so I dont know, to which crs I reprojected the file. I cant reproduce what I did... But I have the orginal file (second image in the post). What now?

Comment: No, the second is also wrong. The extent for lonlat coordinates must be between +/-180/90 (degrees). Your values are much greater, probably also in metres.

Comment: oh, yes! Wrong screenshot. I changed it. The second image shows now the metadata of the good shapefile.

Comment: Looks like UTM 39N, see my screenshot!